# Why is executable size of a MFC dialog built with VS 2012 nearly 3X the size of one built with VS 2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I did an experiment by building the default MFC dialog using VC++ 6.0, VS 2005, VS 2008, VS 2010, and VS 2012.

Each was built using MFC in a static library because the potential users generally don't have privileges to install the required runtimes.  Each used multi-byte char set, was built in release mode, and had support for Winsock.  This was on a Windows 7 machine.  All are 32-bit apps.

The VS 2012 app had the `_AFX_NO_MFC_CONTROLS_IN_DIALOGS` switch defined to make it smaller which did almost nothing.  Here are the results:

```
VC++6.0    204 KB
VS 2005    304 KB
VS 2008   1690 KB
VS 2010   1724 KB
VS 2012   3888 KB
```

---

I was amazed to find that the app built with VS 2012 was over 10 times the size of the one built with 2005.  Is all of this due to security enhancements?

My company is phasing out all but VS 2010 and VS 2012 due to security vulnerabilities in the older IDE's.  I typically build and maintain large and complicated MFC dialog-based apps, and many of them run simultaneously, so I'd like to minimize their total memory footprint.

Besides dumping MFC and moving to C#/WPF or QT, each of which has its own downsides;

- is there some magic compiler setting I can use with VS 2012 to remove some of this bloat?

Comment: Why do you care? 4 MB is **nothing**. Compare that to a Qt application with the same functionality (i.e.: none) weighing in at around 15-20 MB. Reducing memory footprint is nice and all, but 4 MB is nothing to worry about, given that an average browser session easily chews up half a gig.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. Here are some links for you to look at:

- [Reducing the Size of Statically-linked MFC Applications in VC11](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/02/06/10263387.aspx) (I think you already did this without results).
- [Statically linked release MFC EXE size in Visual C++ 2010 vs 2008](http://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2010/05/26/statically-linked-release-mfc-exe-size-in-visual-c-2010-vs-2008/)
- [How to make small statically linked MFC EXEs in Visual C++ 2010](http://tedwvc.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/how-to-make-small-statically-linked-mfc-exes-in-visual-c-2010/)

Comment: Can you augment the links with some steps to take within the post?  So when those links die, and someone finds this answer, they will have at least something?